# JsonConvert.SerializeObject for DataTable - works but Deserialize doesn't

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

I have a DataTable which I convert to json using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. It works fine and here is the results:

```
[
  {
    "String": null,
    "Int": 1,
    "Double": 1.0,
    "Boolean": false,
    "Date": "2022-09-30T00:00:00",
    "DateTime": "2022-09-30T00:00:00",
    "List of strings": [
      "A",
      "C"
    ],
    "List of floats": [
      1.0,
      2.0
    ],
    "List of dates": "[datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)]",
    "Dictionary String - Flaot": {
      "A": 1.0
    },
    "Dictionary String - List of floats": {
      "A": [
        1.0
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "String": null,
    "Int": 2,
    "Double": 2.0,
    "Boolean": true,
    "Date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DateTime": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "List of strings": [
      "B",
      "D"
    ],
    "List of floats": [
      3.0,
      4.0
    ],
    "List of dates": "[datetime.date(2022, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 2, 2)]",
    "Dictionary String - Flaot": {
      "B": 2.0,
      "C": 3.0
    },
    "Dictionary String - List of floats": {
      "B": [
        2.0,
        3.0
      ],
      "C": [
        12.0
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

However when I used `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(aboveJson)` then I got an error:

```
JsonSerializationException: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable: StartObject. Path '[0]['Dictionary String - Flaot']', line 18, position 34.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.GetColumnDataType(JsonReader reader)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.CreateRow(JsonReader reader, DataTable dt, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DataTableConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

How can I fix that?

*Text added to be able to add question...*
*Text added to be able to add question...*
*Text added to be able to add question...*
*Text added to be able to add question...*

Comment: Your JSON looks to complicated for [`DataTableConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs) to infer the column types.  It will infer primitive column types correctly, but not values like `{"B": 2.0, "C": 3.0}` or {`"B": [2.0,3.0],"C": [12.0]}`.  Do **you** know the column types in advance? Or could you use a typed DataTable?

Comment: do not directly serialize/deserialize datatable maybe you can use strongly typed list instead datatable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to flatten all properties with objects

```
    var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

    foreach (JObject item in jArray)
    {
        foreach (var prop in item.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array) prop.Value = string.Join(",", prop.Value);
            else if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                var newValue = "";
                foreach (var prop2 in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
                {
                    if (prop2.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array) newValue = newValue + prop2.Name + ": " + string.Join(",", prop2.Value) + "; ";
                    else newValue = newValue + prop2.Name + ": " + (string)prop2.Value + "; ";
                }
                prop.Value = newValue;
            }
        }
    }

     DataTable dataTable=jArray.ToObject<DataTable>();
```

output

```
[
  {
    "String": null,
    "Int": 1,
    "Double": 1.0,
    "Boolean": false,
    "Date": "2022-09-30T00:00:00",
    "DateTime": "2022-09-30T00:00:00",
    "List of strings": "A,C",
    "List of floats": "1,2",
    "List of dates": "[datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)]",
    "Dictionary String - Flaot": "A: 1; ",
    "Dictionary String - List of floats": "A: 1; "
  },
  {
    "String": null,
    "Int": 2,
    "Double": 2.0,
    "Boolean": true,
    "Date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "DateTime": "2021-01-01T00:00:00",
    "List of strings": "B,D",
    "List of floats": "3,4",
    "List of dates": "[datetime.date(2022, 1, 1), datetime.date(2022, 2, 2)]",
    "Dictionary String - Flaot": "B: 2; C: 3; ",
    "Dictionary String - List of floats": "B: 2,3; C: 12; "
  }
]
```